# Faceted search show tid instead of taxonomy name

Tags: 8, search

I need to create a facet search using taxonomies, I have as a index the taxonomy term name but when I go to search, in the facet I see the tid and not the taxonomy term name. I follow [a tutorial](http://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2016/set-faceted-apache-solr-search-page-on-drupal-8-search-api-solr-and-facets) but I can't found the solution.

***Search Index***

[image]

***Facet***

[image]

***Search***

[image]

There is [one issue in drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2671598#comment-10876200) talking about a TranslateTaxonomyProcessor callback processor but I don't know how to use it. Another issue talkin about the same processor: https://www.drupal.org/node/2673888

***This is the list of my Processors:***

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to check "**Translate entity label**" option to see the name.

By editing Tag facet block you can see that option.

[image]

If you have still same issue.

You need to install [Core Views Facets](https://www.drupal.org/project/core_views_facets) module.
Then select Facet source.

```
View Search content, display Page
```

Added One example o/p screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I did it but then there is nothing to show, the faucet is empty

Comment: Made some changes on answer hopes that will work.

Comment: ok let me know if you are getting any problem.

Comment: this solution works in your enviroment?

Comment: yes added o/p screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46348/discussion-between-adrian-cid-almaguer-and-smalution).